# RegEx rule for a word only if it contains a hyphen

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx rule that filters the word "Automobile" only if it contains a hyphen. Examples: `Auto-mobile`, `Aut-omobile`, `Automobil-e` these cases should be filtered.
If the word does not contain a hyphen, then the word should not be filtered.

I have created the following RegEx rule:

```
\bA-?u-?t-?o-?m-?o-?b-?i-?l-?e\b
```

However, this rule also filters the word without a hyphen.

How could the regex rule be adapted?

Comment: Which programming language / tool do you use? It's probable easier to do this programmatically.

Comment: Try: `\b(?=[a-zA-Z]*-)[a-zA-Z-]+\b`

Comment: And, are multiple hyphens allowed?

Comment: @Jan: I would like to use it in an E-Mail Spam filter, rule for multiple hyphens not necessary.

Comment: @anubhava: The rule should only apply to the word "Automobile", other hyphenated words should not be filtered.

Comment: @Peter: And which programming language?

Comment: @Jan: I would like to use it in a Online GUI where RegEx Rules are possible. I guess it is a PHP program.

Comment: @Peter: Then go with the solution by [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77935546/1231450)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't want `-` at the start and end of the word, you may use this regex for your requirement:

```bash
\b(?=[a-zA-Z]*-)A-?u-?t-?o-?m-?o-?b-?i-?l-?e\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ockoHd/1)

Only important change from your regex is addition of a positive lookahead `(?=[a-zA-Z]*-)` that asserts presence of a `-` after 0 or more alphabets.

Comment: The obvious but right solution :-)